# How to set a red outline border while using BorderImage

Tags: image, qt, qml, qtquick2, border-image

I am using [BorderImage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qml-borderimage.html#cache-prop) to display images on a [GridView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html).

Following is sort of what I am doing:

```
BorderImage {
  source: some_image
  asynchronous: true
  cache: false
}
```

**I want to set a red outline border to my image**. *How can I do that* ?

I looked at the `Border.left`, `Border.right` properties but they just stretch the image.

Comment: Why "*while usintg QML's `BorderImage`*"?

Comment: @derM modified the question. pls check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add a `Rectangle` to your `(Border)Image`

```
BorderImage {
    source: some_image

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: -border.width
        z: -1
        border.width: 4
        color: 'red'
    }
}
```